# jQuery script works in Firefox but not in IE. Why am I not surprised?

Tags: jquery

I'm working with the context of a CMS system and trying to turn seperate div's into tabs.
You can see it at http://www.wtvynews4.com/test I've kludged together some code from a tutorial site.

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {

//When page loads...
$("div[ondblclick$='87119417']").attr("id", "87119417");
$("div[ondblclick$='87119482']").attr("id", "87119482");
$("div[ondblclick$='87119672']").attr("id", "87119672");
$("div[ondblclick$='87119727']").attr("id", "87119727");
$("div[ondblclick$='87119812']").attr("id", "87119812");
$("div[ondblclick$='87119417']").addClass("tab_content");
$("div[ondblclick$='87119482']").addClass("tab_content");
$("div[ondblclick$='87119672']").addClass("tab_content");
$("div[ondblclick$='87119727']").addClass("tab_content");
$("div[ondblclick$='87119812']").addClass("tab_content");

$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.morenewstabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

//On Click Event
$("ul.morenewstabs li").click(function() {

    $("ul.morenewstabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).show(); //Fade in the active ID content
    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

Everything works fine in Firefox but not IE.  can you provide any assistance?  When the page loads the attribute ID's and classes aren't assigned.  I tried changing jQuery(function() {  to $(document).ready(function() still no luck.

Comment: Why not slim it down to only a couple jQuery calls to weed out the problem. After you get one call to work, add another slowly instead of trying a huge heap at once. You are giving a lot of code but not a lot of info that will help in finding the issue.

Comment: Try an `alert($("div[ondblclick$='87119417']").length);` what's IE show?

Comment: returns 0
so it may not be able to find the referenced object.

Comment: Paring the code down to even the first set of attribute lines doesn't net a result.  For some basic reason this script isn't being processed in IE.

Comment: Can you post an example of the markup?  I would bet IE is correctly recognizing this as an event instead of an attribute, but you can probably simplify it overall by writing one jQuery function to hookup...I can show you how if we had the html.

Answer (score 0):

From a very [quick search](http://jerakeen.org/test/unicode/), it might be something to do with the `charset` attribute to your script tag. Try removing it and see if that helps. If it does, and you need UTF-8 support, there are [other options](http://www.meanfreepath.com/support/javascript_charsets.html).

Comment: Strip it down to one item only, and remove all of your onclick stuff. Take it right back to just adding a class. Then add one line at a time until you see which line doesn't work, then we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. IE searches attributes **case-sensitive**. Plus it appears not to recognize `[attrib$="value"]` selectors. Instead I had to use `[attrib*="value"]` Thanks for everyone's help.